# Dudas sobre el funcionamiento del EJ

Tags: java, hilos

HE de hacer esto, 19 (lector-escritor). Simula el acceso y escritura a una base de datos. Para ello, lanza 20 hilos simultáneamente, 10 de lectura y 10 de escritura de un entero. Los hilos de escritura incrementarán en uno el entero mientras no haya otro hilo de escritura escribiendo o un hilo de lectura leyendo. Los de lectura pueden leer e imprimir el entero aunque haya otros hilos de lectura pero no mientras haya uno de escritura escribiendo. Usa la clase Semaphore de Java.

Pongo lo que he hecho y comento mis dudas.

```
public class Lector extends Thread {

    private Semaphore semaforo;

    public Lector(String nombre, Semaphore s) {
        super(nombre);
        this.semaforo = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " intentando leer");
        try {
            semaforo.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " leyendo");
        try {
            sleep((int) (Math.random() * 50));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        semaforo.release();
        System.out.println(getName() + " ya ha leído");
    }
}

public class Escritor extends Thread {

    private Semaphore semaforo;

    public Escritor(String nombre, Semaphore s) {
        super(nombre);
        this.semaforo = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " intentando escribir");
        try {
            semaforo.acquire(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " escribiendo");
        try {
            sleep((int) (Math.random() + 50));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        semaforo.release(5);
        System.out.println(getName() + " ya ha escrito");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            new Escritor("Escritor" + i, semaforo).start();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            new Lector("Lector" + i, semaforo).start();
        }
    }

}
```

Mi principal duda es porque 5 permisos en el semaforo?porque no 1 o 10 o 7?es indiferente?

cunado doy a run ocurre esto

```
Escritor1 intentando escribir
Escritor5 intentando escribir
Escritor4 intentando escribir
Escritor5 escribiendo
Escritor3 intentando escribir
Escritor2 intentando escribir
Escritor7 intentando escribir
Escritor6 intentando escribir
Escritor9 intentando escribir
Escritor8 intentando escribir
Lector2 intentando leer
Lector1 intentando leer
Escritor10 intentando escribir
Lector3 intentando leer
Lector7 intentando leer
Lector5 intentando leer
Lector9 intentando leer
Lector10 intentando leer
Lector6 intentando leer
Lector4 intentando leer
Lector8 intentando leer
Escritor5 ya ha escrito
Escritor4 escribiendo
Escritor4 ya ha escrito
Escritor3 escribiendo
Escritor3 ya ha escrito
Escritor1 escribiendo
Escritor1 ya ha escrito
Escritor2 escribiendo
Escritor2 ya ha escrito
Escritor7 escribiendo
Escritor6 escribiendo
Escritor7 ya ha escrito
Escritor6 ya ha escrito
Escritor9 escribiendo
Escritor9 ya ha escrito
Escritor8 escribiendo
Escritor8 ya ha escrito
Lector2 leyendo
Lector1 leyendo
Lector2 ya ha leído
Lector1 ya ha leído
Escritor10 escribiendo
Escritor10 ya ha escrito
Lector10 leyendo
Lector9 leyendo
Lector3 leyendo
Lector5 leyendo
Lector7 leyendo
Lector3 ya ha leído
Lector4 leyendo
Lector6 leyendo
Lector10 ya ha leído
Lector7 ya ha leído
Lector8 leyendo
Lector4 ya ha leído
Lector9 ya ha leído
Lector5 ya ha leído
Lector6 ya ha leído
Lector8 ya ha leído
```

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre cuando el código es ejecutado? Creo que no haría nada porque el semáforo sólo ofrece un recurso y todos los threads piden 5

Comment: lo pongo en la pregunta

Comment: Ah, veo que los lectores sólo consumen 1, gracias por añadir la ejecución

Comment: En teoria los lectores pueden consumir mas de 1 segun el enunciado esque estoy un poco pegado corrige el ejercicio si crees que no es asi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He modificado basándome en el problema y tus clases,  para que puedas aprender una buenas practicas, he agregado una clase BaseDatos que contiene un contador estático para simular el acceso.
El proceso utiliza un semáforo con 10 permir que serán requeridos en caso de escritura para bloquear cualquier otra acción de escritura como lectura, y los porcesos  de lectura únicamente utilizaran 1 permit en caso de lectura concurrente ninguno sera bloqueado.

Clase principal:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Ejecucion {

    public static final int NUM_HILOS_MAX = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Inicializamos el semaforo con 10 porque sera el numero maximos de procesos de lectura
        Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(NUM_HILOS_MAX);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            new Escritor("Escritor" + i, semaforo).start();
            new Lector("Lector" + i, semaforo).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Clase para simular Base de Datos:

```
public class BaseDatos {
    static int count = 0;
}
```

Clases de escritura y lectura:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Escritor extends Thread {

    private Semaphore semaforo;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Escritor(String nombre, Semaphore semaforo) {
        super(nombre);
        this.semaforo = semaforo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + "\t intentando escribir");
        try {
            bloquearTodo();
            // Utilizamos String.format() como una buena práctica para mostrar mensajes,
            // además usamos ++BaseDatos.count para que primero incremente el valor y después lo imprima,
            // si fuera BaseDatos.count++ primero imprime el valor y después lo incrementa.

            System.out.println(String.format("%s escribiendo, valor anterior: %o - nuevo valor: %o ", getName(), BaseDatos.count, ++BaseDatos.count));

            // Definimos que el tiempo de escritura será entre 0 y 4
            int i = random.nextInt(4);

            // En mi opinión esta es una forma de dormir un hilo que favorece un código más legible.
            // Puedes utilizar otras unidades de medida como MILLISECONDS, MICROSECONDS, etc. Solo recuerda aumentar el valor máximo del random
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(i);

            System.out.println(String.format("%s ya ha escrito - tiempo escritura: %o ", getName(), i));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Si lo que quieres es imprimir la excepción debes utilizar printStackTrace() para ver la traza completa.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // En caso que la ejecución del programa falle se deben liberar los recursos en finally
            // para garantizar que los recursos siempre son liberados después de ser adquiridos.
            liberarTodo();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Debido a que el enunciado dice que solo un hilo puede escribir solicitamos el total de los permit para que no
     * se ejecuten más procesos de lectura y de escritura.
     */
    private void bloquearTodo() throws InterruptedException {
        this.semaforo.acquire(Ejecucion.NUM_HILOS_MAX);
    }

    /**
     * Liberamos el total de los permit adquiridos al inicio con el método release(Ejecucion.NUM_HILOS_MAX), si solo utilizamos release() liberaríamos 1 permit
     * lo cual bloquearia todas las ejecuciones siguientes de escritura que necesitan 10 permit.
     */
    private void liberarTodo() {
        this.semaforo.release(Ejecucion.NUM_HILOS_MAX);
    }

}

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Lector extends Thread {


    private Semaphore semaforo;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Lector(String nombre, Semaphore semaforo) {
        super(nombre);
        this.semaforo = semaforo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + "\t\t intentando leer");
        try {
            // Adquirimos 1 permit para lectura.
            semaforo.acquire();

            System.out.println(String.format("%s Valor de lectura: %o", getName(), BaseDatos.count));

            // Quitamos el sleep para que las lecturas sean más rápidas puedas ver el funcionamiento correcto.
//            int i = random.nextInt(2);
//            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(i);

            System.out.println(String.format("%s ya he leído", getName()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            semaforo.release();
        }
    }

}
```

Los permit sirven como una unidad para definir si un proceso puede ejecutarse, 
en caso que sea una lectura obtendremos 1 permit quedando con 9 permit libres, de esta forma se podrían ejecutar 9 más de lectura simultánea, en el caso que sea una escritura solicitamos todos los permit.

Por ejemplo si se ejecutase un proceso de escritura y hubiesen 8 permit libres, reservaría los 8 y esperaría a que los 2 procesos de lectura finalicen para obtener los 2 permit faltantes, al tener todos los permite reservados si otro proceso de lectura o escritura quiere ejecutarse tendrá que esperar a que se liberen y obtener la cantidad necesaria para la ejecución (1 lectura y 10 para escritura).

Comment: muchas gracias funciona canela si tengo alguna duda te comento

Answer (score 2):

La forma en la que funciona el semáforo de tu código es la siguiente:

```
Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(1);
```

Creas un semáforo con 1 permiso.

Entonces lanzas los 10 hilos lectores y los 10 hilos escritores. Lo que ocurre es que los hilos escritores requieren 5 permisos para "pasar" el semáforo, con lo que se quedan siempre parados. Los hilos lectores sólo consumen 1, por lo que pueden pasar pero sólo de uno en uno: el resto ha de esperar.

Tienes que encontrar una solución en la que los hilos escritores bloqueen todo, porque te piden que sólo puedan entrar de uno en uno y además sin lectores, pero que los lectores puedan entrar todos a la vez, si es necesario. La solución más simple es crear un semáforo con el mismo número de permisos que de hilos lectores (o un múltiplo del mismo).

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Main1 {

    private static final int NUM_HILOS = 10;
    private static int registro = 0;

    public static class Lector extends Thread {

        private Semaphore semaforo;

        public Lector(String nombre, Semaphore s) {
            super(nombre);
            this.semaforo = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(getName() + " intentando leer");
            try {
                semaforo.acquire();
                System.out.println(getName() + " leyendo: el valor es " + registro);
                semaforo.release();
                System.out.println(getName() + " ya ha leído");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

    public static class Escritor extends Thread {

        private Semaphore semaforo;

        public Escritor(String nombre, Semaphore s) {
            super(nombre);
            this.semaforo = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(getName() + " intentando escribir");
            try {
                semaforo.acquire(NUM_HILOS);

                System.out.println(getName() + " escribiendo");
                registro++;
                semaforo.release(NUM_HILOS);
                System.out.println(getName() + " ya ha escrito");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(NUM_HILOS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_HILOS; i++) {
            new Escritor("Escritor" + i, semaforo).start();
            new Lector("Lector" + i, semaforo).start();
        }
    }
}
```